# Ransack search on Rails Engine: No results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, ransack, search-form

Trying to create a site wide search form that search for products containing some string.

I´m using a slightly modified version o Shoppe Gem. It´s an Engine for managing a shopping cart, products, orders, etc...

I´ve got it uploaded in this repository: [egallart´s shoppe fork](https://github.com/egallart/shoppe)

I´ve update shoppe dependencies to match current master version of ransack.

---

I have coded my search form in application layout, in header partial, for search in name column of the database.
When I try some string that I know exists, I don´t get any results in the view.

Here´s the relevant code of my MVC.

### Application controller

In main app: app/controllers/application_controller.html.erb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_search

  def set_search
    @q = Shoppe::Product.ransack(params[:q])
    @products = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end

end
```

I need this to initialize @q site wide, because I´ve got the form in a partial that shows in header in every page of the site.

I´m not sure this is the correct way to do this.

### Product controller

Located in main app.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def search
    @q = Shoppe::Product.ransack(params[:q])
    @products = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end

end
```

### Product Model

Located inside Shoppe::Engine

I didn´t touch anything related to ransack, there is no especific ransack settings in the engine .

### Search partial view

In main app:
views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/menuhorizontal' %>
```

And inside views/layouts/_menuhorizontal.html.erb

```
<%= render 'products/search' %>
```

And inside views/products/_search.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @q, url: search_products_path, method: :get, html: { id: "searchbox"} do |f| %>
<%= f.search_field :name_cont, html: { class: "search_query form-control", id: "search_query_top" } %>
<%= f.button "#{'<span>Buscar</span>'}".html_safe, class: "btn btn-default button-search", name: "submit_search" %>
<% end %>
```

### Search results view

views/products/search.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
<%= p.name %>
<% end %>
```

### Routes.rb in main app.

In config/routes.rb I´ve set:

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

### Routes.rb in Shoppe::Engine.

In config/routes.rb I didn´t touch anything. This is what is shown in Shoppe::Engine vanilla version related to :products:

```
resources :products do
  resources :variants
  resources :localisations, controller: "product_localisations"
  collection do
    get :import
    post :import
  end
  member do
    get :clone
  end
end
```

## The most important thing is:

When I try ransack search in rails console I don´t get any results either. That behaviour is whats feels weird and get me lost.

This is what I get in console:

```
[2] pry(main)> Shoppe::Product.ransackable_attributes
=> ["id",
"parent_id",
"name",
"sku",
"permalink",
"description",
"short_description",
"active",
"weight",
"price",
"cost_price",
"tax_rate_id",
"created_at",
"updated_at",
"featured",
"in_the_box",
"stock_control",
"default",
"ean",
"price_on_web",
"length",
"width",
"height",
"moq"]

[4] pry(main)> Shoppe::Product.ransack(name_cont: 'Acople')
=> Ransack::Search<class: Shoppe::Product, base: Grouping
<conditions: [Condition <attributes: ["name"], predicate: cont, 
values:     ["Acople"]>], combinator: and>>
```

NOTE: 'Acople' string exists in database column name for one product.

### Another weird behaviour

When I ransack search by sku: (sku_cont:) I get proper results.

name: is a string and sku: is a string too!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem is that Shoppe uses globalize for translations, and certain columns in the database don´t contain any information because It uses other table to store that information.

Now I´m looking a way to search in that translations.

#### update

Follow this link for more information

[Ransack search and translations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999680/ransack-search-and-translations)